# Preventing simultaneous overwrites when editing a MySQL-row through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

*I am uncertain how to ask this concisely, so I will explain it through situational-context.*

User-A decides he wants to modify a MySQL-row via an HTML-form.
Simultaneously, User-B decides he also wants to modify the same MySQL-row in the same way.

We will say the MySQL-row is a text-field which contains the text, `'Can\'t touch this'`

The two users have no knowledge of eachothers intentions.

User-A makes a significant change to the MySQL-row and saves it to the database.
The MySQL-row becomes `'Can\'t touch this was a popular track by the Hip-Hop artist M.C. Hammer.'`

User-B makes a minor-change to the MySQL-row and saves it to the database.
The MySQL-row becomes `'Cannot touch this. Please avoid contractions.'`

Because User-B decided to modify the MySQL-row before User-A finished his modification, the Modification User-A made gets overwritten by the modification made by User-B.

How do scripts which allow simultaneous editing of database-rows (such as MediaWiki, or any other wiki-software) deal with this?

Comment: AFAIK mediawiki doesn't allow simultaneous editing of their documents. Last time I checked they indicate whether someone is currently editing the document and tell you to avoid making changes in the meanwhile.

Comment: A few weeks ago, SO allowed this simultaneous editing, bluntly overwriting the previous edits without notice. At the moment this site gives an error message that someone else edited a post (or proposed an edit), thereby disallowing me to (temporarily) save an edited message, letting me waste time and energy in useless editing. BTW, I think you interchanged the results in the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @sombe That is the method I previously used. I however, found a flaw since the lock-out had an expiry-time that users legitimately making a long edit would exceed and then be unable to submit because it became free and was locked by someone else.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes, I just realized I mixed User-A and User-B in the last sentence. Sorry about that! As if it wasnt confusing enough.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to add at least one extra field to any tables which can be edited in this manner. Something to indicate that the row's locked. For added usefulness, you should record when then the row was locked and by whom.

A timed job to unlock records which were abandoned would also be needed, otherwise someone could just edit every record in sequence, abandon the edit, and lock up the entire database.

Something similar happens here on SO. If you're editing someone's question and someone else saves an edit while you're working away, you get a notice that the question's been changed and your edits are no longer valid.

Comment: There is even a disadvantage to the timed-lockout though. Legitimately, someone might be making a huge revision which might take an amount of time way beyond the expiry-time of the lock-out.

Comment: True, but then you could use an ajax heartbeat to refresh the lock.

Comment: True! I may just go this route. As much as I dread using Ajax in my scripts, it does have its uses. Now, just to figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 4):

You can use row-level locking to force edits to be done in a series (as opposed to simultaneously).  This is often what you'll want to do over devising a way to merge the changes, it'll save you some hassle later.

It also helps if you use a timestamp and sanity variable in the form that sends submission changes to your database / processing script.  Then you can check this against the database before writing to it, and if not; give the user a message that there were posts or changes before his/her own.. and let htem see it before commiting their own.

Comment: Row level locking would not work in a web-based situation, as the db connection is generally severed when the current request finishes. The lock would be held for the duration of the request, then released and stay unlocked until the next request. And in the mean time, other users can come in and edit the same record.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest methods I know is to add a version field to the table. When you read a record you fetch the version field and add it as a hidden field to your edit form. When the data is posted back after editing, you fetch the record and check if the version field in the db still matches the one of your form. If not, then the record has been edited by someone else in the meantime (how you handle this is up to you). If it matches, you alter the data and increment the version number. Or in other words, a basic implementation of optimistic locking...

Comment: Well I do not have a version number; but instead I store all revisions in a separate table with a time-field which acts as both the time the revision was added and the time the actual-page was last modified. And I was thinking about passing that value as a hidden-form-field and verifying if it matches its database-value upon form-submission.

Comment: That would indeed amount to the same functionality. You'd also have an easy way to check if there have been changes in the meantime (if the timestamp doesn't match).

Answer (score 1):

I liked the Wesley Murch method.
Also you can allow multiple users to change the same document, and employ a merge while the second commit is done. You will need to hold the original document before editing.

Comment: Merging the revisions sounds very intensive. Although, I would definitely try it if I even knew where to begin with it.